# My ubuntu upgrade just stopped

Tags: upgrade

[image: screenshot]

I was using 16.04, then a new version 18.04 upgrade popped up. I just started it, then the window just stopped. I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Can you close firefox?

Comment: Make a backup of your files if you don't already have it! **now!** Then wait for a while, maybe it's just stuck and will move on later. Maybe not, then you need to kill that window and have good luck :-P